# Is there a way to use markdown in Microsoft Live Writer?

Tags: windows-7, blogging, windows-live-writer

I love the coding that Super User and all of the other StackExchange sites uses for editing/created questions and answers... markdown.  It's easy to use.  I'm wondering if there is a way to enable the use of markdown with Live Writer?  Is there a plugin to do this?  A hack or work around?

Comment: Out of curiosity: Which blogging system do you use (server-side)?

Comment: @Tobias mainly for the superuser.blogoverflow.com which is a stack exchange server using wordpress but I also use blogger personally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any markdown plugin for Live Writer, but there are other text editors that accept markdown.

A well-known example is [WriteMonkey](http://writemonkey.com/).

Comment: Although this is not directly the answer to the question (anyway, switching to WriteMonkey would solve the problem in any case), I agree with you (+1).

Comment: Although I'm not looking for a text editor, there appears to be no other options... bounty is yours!

Comment: Note: See the new answer by fresky.

Answer (score 3):

I created a Markdown plugin for Windows Live Writer called [MarkdownInLiveWriter](https://github.com/fresky/MarkdownInLiveWriter). You can have a try.